# Do synchronized methods have locks of their own?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking

Suppose I have

```
class myClass {

    synchronized methodA { };

    synchronized methodB { };
}
```

Does it mean that there are 2 implicit locks? One for methodA and one for B? I was reading Cracking the Coding Interview by Gayle McDowell, and she says that locking happens at the level of method + object, as opposed to object. I was under the impression that myClass simply has one lock and every synchronized method uses that. Can anyone explain ?

Comment: lock is obtained on an object, not on method itself

Answer (score 4):

This

```
synchronized void methodA 
{
  //code
}
```

is equivalent to

```
void methodA 
{
  synchronized(this)
  {
    //code
  }

}
```

So, `synchronized` in front of a method will use the instance of the object itself as a lock.

Answer (score 0):

Both of this methods used same lock.
Every object in java has his internal mutex.

```
synchronized void method() {}
```

and

```
synchronized(this) {}
```

used same lock.

But if you try synchronized on static method - it will use different locks:

```
static synchronized method() { // used Class lock ! not object lock
}
```